# Strange compiler error with return types inside lambda inside task run

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

I have the following method:

```
    public Task<List<T>?> ReadXmlAsync<T>(IEnumerable<string> xmlFileEntries)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var xmlDtos = new List<T>();
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            foreach (var xml in xmlFileEntries)
            {
                using var fs = new FileStream(xml, FileMode.Open);

                if (serializer.Deserialize(fs) is not T dto)
                    return null;

                xmlDtos.Add(dto);
            }

            return xmlDtos;
        });
    }
```

It reads xml files frpm paths in `xmlFileEntries`, tries to deserialize them and returns either null if any deserialization fails or deserialized collection `xmlDtos`. If I want to expand its functionality and return not only null if deserialization fails but also path to the damaged xml file (variable called `xml`), so my method should look something like that:

```
    public Task<(List<T>?, string?)> ReadXmlAsync<T>(IEnumerable<string> xmlFileEntries)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var xmlDtos = new List<T>();
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            foreach (var xml in xmlFileEntries)
            {
                using var fs = new FileStream(xml, FileMode.Open);

                if (serializer.Deserialize(fs) is not T dto)
                    return (null, xml);

                xmlDtos.Add(dto);
            }

            return (xmlDtos, null);
        });
    }
```

But it does not work, compiler underscores `return (null, xml);` and `return (xmlDtos, null);` throwing CS8030 on `return` keyword:

```
CS8030: Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value.
```

CS8135 and CS1662 on a tuple:

```
CS8135: Tuple with 2 elements cannot be converted to type 'object'
```

But if I don't return null instead of string (replace `return (xmlDtos, null);` with, for example `return (xmlDtos, string.Empty);`) compiler stops giving errors. What am I doing wrong? May it be that I don't understand how lambda works correctly?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the type parameters of Task.Run, or replace the returned null with default(string?), that should help the type inference

Comment: @JonasHøgh, I cannot explicitly set the type parameter because I need this method to be generic. I have replaced null with default(string?), compiler stopped giving error but now it shows warning CS 8619, so there is a mismatch in nullability declaration.

Comment: Why not make this async method, erm, async?   Wrapping non-async code in a Task.Run isn't great, especially when it's not really required.

Comment: @Neil, I don't understand what you mean. Can you provide an example please?

Comment: Well, I meant an explicit type parameter containing T as suggested in the answer below. I think that should eliminate the warning as well

Comment: @JonasHøgh, wow, I did not understand your answer because I did not know that I can provide an explicit type to Task.Run. Now it works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: As a side-note, you might find this article interesting: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) by Stephen Toub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Task.Run` can take several different types of delegate parameters, and the compiler is having a hard time figuring out which type you're passing in to it. You can help it by doing one or more of the following:

- Cast the `null` in the return types: `return ((List<T>?)null, xml);` and `return (xmlDtos, (string?) null);`
- Provide an explicit generic type to Task.Run: `Task.Run<(List<T>?, string?)>(...)`

Comment: I tried first advice and compiler started to complain about nullability declaration mismatch (CS8619).

Comment: Providing an explicit type worked, thanks!

Comment: I updated the first option to avoid the compiler warning, but the explicit generic type is probably easiest anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Why wrap the non-async functionality in a task?  Just make this method async, then you don't need Task.Run.

```
public Task<(List<T>?, string?)> ReadXmlAsync<T>(IEnumerable<string> xmlFileEntries)
{
    var xmlDtos = new List<T>();
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    foreach (var xml in xmlFileEntries)
    {
        using var fs = new FileStream(xml, FileMode.Open);

        if (serializer.Deserialize(fs) is not T dto)
            return Task.FromResult((default(List<T>), xml));

        xmlDtos.Add(dto);
    }

    return Task.FromResult((xmlDtos, default(string)));
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/vfeZpE

Comment: Why is it bad? Can you please provide some links for me to read about it in more details?

Comment: I mean I don't understand why Task.Run exists if its purpose not to make sync block of code an awaitable Task which can be run by a separate thread from thread pool and not on the calling thread

Comment: "Just make this method async"--you're actually making the method synchronous. While it's true that many people abuse `Task.Run` to make things parallel when they really only needed to be asynchronous, the OP did not provide enough information for us to presume they don't need this task to complete on a different thread. What if they have a dedicated UI thread and they don't want to freeze the UI while they read the XML file?

Comment: The only case you should be using Task.Run for is for CPU bound methods.  Your code is using IO (deserialising from a file), therefore you shouldn't use it.  https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html